# Cocoa App booting splash screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My Mac app connects to a remote db which takes about 10 seconds to connect and pull data. This time cannot be shortened due to framework initialisation and network latency etc.

I want put a splash screen from the initial app launch time to when the app is ready and done it’s thing.

I have tried `applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification` method but it does not display the splash screen until the app is up, which makes sense, as the AppDelegate seem to be the last object created and the App controller gets init’d completely before the whole app “will finishing launching” which is where the delay is.

Is there any way to invoke this window as soon as the dock tile starts bouncing?

I know I will get shot down for optimising, but no further steps can be taken to speed this process up.

Comment: Can't you move the invokation of this time consuming initialization process to `applicationDidFinisLaunchingWithOptions`? By then you could first display a splash screen or even a modal view containing a progress bar of any kind and then start the initialization process. By doing so the total init time should not change, at least not significantly, but the users expeience some much quicker start up and his paitence is satisfied by the progress bar (or spinner or whatever).

Comment: @HermannKlecker I can try that, but I think that method still sits with the AppDelegate. The ‘slow invocation’ is contained in a model object which puts the data into an array which is owned by the app controller.

Comment: Better practice is to display your UI and disable UI elements that need the connection, displaying a progress indicator and possibly messaging.

Comment: uchuugaka is right. Don't block your UI. Among other things, I may want to visit the Preferences or quit your application while you're setting up this connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you could dispatch your time consuming task to a background thread asynchronously with GCD so that the app delegate can move on:

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // time consuming task
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

you can call dispatch_get_main_queue() to do your onerous tasks on the main thread as opposed to the background thread if they involve changes to the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.This app is for OS X not iOS, so unless I am mistaken your suggestion only applies to iOS.

Comment: Nice idea, but data fetch is already running on another thread. The ‘data object’ is running in the main thread as it is accessed by bindings in the UI.

Comment: if you dispatch async to the main thread (dispatch_get_main_queue()) from the app delegate, the app delegate should return before the block starts executing.

Comment: Genius! Well sort of. Did a bit of juggling and dispatching then moved some stuff around start–up order wise and all seems good to go. Thanks.

Comment: I agree though that while it gets the job done, it's a bit of a gimmick. Probably you should change your code so that you can put all the UI logic in the app controller and execute it directly after setting the splash screen

Comment: All of the UI logic bar the splash is in the app controller.